# how to set path for excel file in django

Tags: python, django, pandas

I'm using pandas ExcelWriter and `openpyxl` for creating excel in Django project.  how would I set particular path in my project directory to save the created excel? thanks, in advance.

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
df_view = obj_master.get_employee()
writer = ExcelWriter('PythonExportt.xlsx')
df_view.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: where do you want to store the excel files ?

Comment: in Django project folder directory  with name backup

Comment: it means in the directory `myproject/backup/` right

Comment: yes correct@Bijoy

Answer (score 1):

use `./path/to/file` to declare a local path

UPDATE

alternatively you can define the path in settings.py and then import it to any django file as

Settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Somewhere in Django:

```
from django.conf import settings
def write_to_excel(dataFrame, sheetName): 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(settings.BASE_DIR, engine='xlsxwriter')
dataFrame.to_excel(writer, sheetName='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: where would I declare it in Django?

Comment: write = ExcelWriter('./PythonExportt.xlsx') This will write the file into the same folder as manage.py file.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way is to write the Pandas Excel stream to a memory stream, and then wrap this into a HTTP response:

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter

XLSX_MIME = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'

def some_excelfile_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type=XLSX_MIME)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="PythonExport.xlsx"'

    # obtain obj_master
    # ...
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(response, engine='xlsxwriter')

    df_view = obj_master.get_employee()
    df_view.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
    writer.save()
    return response
```

Then you can use a `url` that maps to this `some_excelfile_view`. If a user then visists that URL, it will perform a file download for the Excel file.

Comment: thanks, Willem. please help me in setting a path the saved excel

Comment: @selvakumar: but this looks like a bad idea, since it makes the webservice more persistent than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To get the path of the project directory, regardless of any constraint. The `settings.py` has the value of the project directory in `BASE_DIR`, you should import it and save the file

```
from myproject.settings import BASE_DIR
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import os

save_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'backup')

df_view = obj_master.get_employee()
writer = ExcelWriter('{}/PythonExportt.xlsx'.format(save_path))
df_view.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: No such file or directory: '/home/selava/prj/backup/PythonExportt.xlsx' error occurs , I want to create new excel file in that path

Comment: have you created a folder called `backup` in root directory of your project ?

Comment: Yes I have created

Comment: where have you created the `backup` folder, can you describe the path of the file inwhich you have written above code, and path of your `backup` folder.

Comment: because this works for me, am able to create the file